# Scala Iterating Tuple Map

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, iterator

I have a map of key value pairs and I am trying to fetch the value given a key, however although it returns me a value it comes along with some, any idea how can I get rid of it?
My code is:

```
val jsonmap = simple.split(",\"").toList.map(x => x.split("\":")).map(x => Tuple2(x(0), x(1))).toMap
val text = jsonmap.get("text")
```

Where "text" is the key and I want the value that it is mapped to, I am currently getting the following output:

```
Some("4everevercom")
```

I tried using flatMap instead of Map but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `apply` method. `Seq`, `Set` and `Map` implement different `apply` methods, the difference being the main distinction between each one.

As a syntactic sugar, `.apply` can be omitted in `o.apply(x)`, so you'd just have to do this:

```
val text = jsonmap("text") // pass "key" to apply and receive "value"
```

For `Seq`, `apply` takes an index and return a value, as you used in your own example:

```
x(0), x(1)
```

For `Set`, `apply` takes a value, and returns a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use getOrElse, as [@Brian stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593097/298389), or 'apply' method and deal with absent values on your own:

```
val text: String = jsonmap("text")
// would trow java.util.NoSuchElementException, if no key presented
```

Moreover, you can set some default value so Map can fallback to it, if no key found:

```
val funkyMap = jsonmap.get("text").withDefaultValue("")
funkyMap("foo")
// if foo or any other key is not presented in map, "" will be returned
```

Use it, if you want to have default value for **all** missing keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getOrElse` which gets the value of `Some` if there is one or the default value that you specify. If the key exists in the map, you will get the value from `Some`. If the key does not exist, you will get the value specified.

```
scala> val map = Map(0 -> "foo")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> foo)

scala> map.get(0)
res3: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> map.getOrElse(1, "bar")
res4: String = bar
```

Also, see this for info on Scala's Some and None Options: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-option-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just offering additional options that might help you work with `Option` and other similar structures you'll find in the standard library.

You can also iterate (map) over the Option.  This works since `Option` is an `Iterable` containing either zero or one element.

```
myMap.get(key) map { value =>
  // use value...
}
```

Equivalently, you can use a `for` if you feel it makes for clearer code:

```
for (value <- myMap.get(key)) {
  // use value...
}
```